# Expected value in exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Sam will sell car to the first person to offer at least 2000. offers on his car are independent and follow an Expo(1000) distribution.

• probability that an offer will be at least 2000?

> $e^{-2000/1000} = 0.1353$

• On average, how many offers will it take until Jack gets an offer of at least 2000?

> 1/0.1353 = 7.39

• What is the expected amount that he will get for his car (i.e. the expected value of the first offer that’s above $2000)? (Hint: No need to do integrals for this!)
>

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Exponential RVs famously satisfy the memorylessness property $$ P(X>m+n\mid X> m) = P(X>n).$$